# change UIPicker highlighted tab width

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipicker

I am using UIPicker in one of my project.

I have UIPickerView of size & position as

```
 58, 264, 204, 216
  x   y  width height
```

I am doing iOS 7 compatible app.

in iOS 7, I want to show of width 204 only, but in iOS 6 and earlier version, I want to show of width 300.

For this below is what I did.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    if (IS_DEVICE_RUNNING_IOS_7_AND_ABOVE()) {
    NSLog(@"changing font...");
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 204, 44)]; // your frame, so picker gets "colored"

        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:localize(@"myFontName") size:14];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        label.text = [arrayGender objectAtIndex:row];

        return label;
    } else {
        [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 264, 300, 216)];
        pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 260, 44)];

        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:14];

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayGender objectAtIndex:row]];
        return label;
    }
}
```

This is is working perfectly.

The problem comes in highlighter that is there. The highlighter size is fixed to 204 (this is the size-width set in IB for UIPicker)

Any idea how to tackle this highlighter?

By highlighter, below is sample what I meant.

[image]

Below is the actual image of what I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  solved it by reversing the stuff.

In IB I created UIPicker view of width 320 and in code I adjusted the width.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should make own UIView as an custom Selection Indicator. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579133/ios-how-to-add-a-custom-selectionindicator-to-a-uipickerview) for details.